# Add load command to mach-o binary

Tags: environment-variables, dylib, mach-o, dyld

Is it possible to add an LC_LOAD_DYLIB to a binary? There has been protection against DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES being used so I need another to load a dylib into an app

Comment: This doesn't make sense. "There has been protection?" Please clarify.

Comment: Well that's my assumption. DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES doesn't work. It's not a problem with the library because I can insert it manually with gdb using dlopen

Answer (score 4):

I open-sourced [`optool`](https://github.com/alexzielenski/optool) which does exactly this.